# NodeJs on an Ubuntu docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, containers

I am moving my windows hosted SPA app into a Linux container.  I am somewhat familiar with Ubuntu, so I was going to use that.

The [NodeJs page on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) shows containers for several Debian versions and Alpine.

But nothing for Ubuntu.

**Is Ubuntu not recommended for use with NodeJs by the NodeJs Team?**

Or is it just too much work to keep lots of Linux distros of NodeJs preped, so the Node team stopped at Debian and Alpine?

Or is there some other reason?....

Comment: depending on your NPM packages, i'd just start with alpine and see where it gets you.  We have a lot of varying packages and it's been pretty much spot-on for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu is too heavy to have it as a base container for running a node application as a server. Debian and Alpine are much more lightweight compared to Ubuntu.

Just on top of that, having some knowledge of Ubuntu, debian and alpine wouldn't be a big change. At the end of the day Ubuntu is somewhat built on top of debian, and they're linux distros so you should be fine. Especially that you'd need to do your configure steps ones, save them as part of the container image and you're done. Every time it will make the same container with the right setup. The beauty of containers.

Comment: When you say "too heavy" what do you mean?  Because of docker layers, file size should not be a big deal.  Is it "heavy" in other ways?

Comment: Due to its size, resources required, etc. startup time could be an important issue on when you'd want to switch to a "lighter" base so you can layer more things on top (and those minimal as well) in order to keep the resources and size low so you have a nice and quick startup.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is just a really heavy base and is going to add a ton of packages into the container that most likely are unnecessary. If you're going to be building production grade containers, Alpine is usually the go-to. It has a minimal amount of libraries installed, reducing the overall size of the container, and should be closest to "bare-minimum" that your application needs to run. I'd start there.

Comment: When you say it is a "really heavy base" what do you mean?  Because of docker layers, file size should not be a big deal.  Is it "heavy" in other ways?

Comment: I guess it really depends on your use case. If you've got multiple images that use the ubuntu base, then you'll still have that ubuntu base, but it won't be duplicated for each container running. However, if you're running in production across multiple nodes, each node will need that base as well, and in some cases like my company [Cycle](https://cycle.io) we flatten the images for deployment to simplify things and guarantee that the container won't fall prey to cached layer issues etc.